# rvest - get #text after a specific tag?

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape text off of [this website](http://atla.avatarspirit.net/transcripts.php?num=120). I can get all of the speaking character's names with this:

```
url1 <- "http://atla.avatarspirit.net/transcripts.php?num=120"
webpage <- read_html(url1)
webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("b") %>%
  html_text()
```

But I can't figure out how to also pull what the characters said. When I inspect it, it looks like the quotes are in `#text` but I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like this (It is not complete, but gets what characters said):

```
webpage %>% 
html_nodes(xpath="//body//b/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>% 
xml_text(trim=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

So taking a look there are 2 options that I saw. One is if you use "blockquote" it pulls all the text down. Maybe a bit of formatting will achieve what you are looking for.

```
webpage %>% 
html_nodes("blockquote") %>%
html_text()
```

The other option is using "i" this pulls the text down a little cleaner; however it doesn't grab all the text responses.

```
webpage %>% 
html_nodes("i") %>%
html_text()
```